# vb.net "The requested address is not valid in its context"

Tags: vb.net, tcp

I have built a simple TCP/ IP connection program which works as expected using the IP address found in the CMD configip command its structure is as follows xxx.xxx.xxx.XX (Private IPv4) however I want to use the IP address that's is linked to my domain name its format is XX.xxx.xxx.xxx (Public IPv4) however using this IP address format results in an error exception telling me that "The requested address is not valid in its context" how do I fix this?

just as extra background information I'm building an TCP/ IP web server application hens why I want to be able to use a domain name linked to that Ip type of IP address build up...

Answer (score 0):

I see now I just use my xxx.xxx.xxx.XX ip and have the router portforward my url too this private IP